# Problems with css

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Here's a css3 dropdown menu problem on IE.

With the following css:

```
/* Main Navigation */

#nav {
list-style: none;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: -30px;
z-index: 2000;
}

#nav li {
float: right;
position: relative;
}

#nav a {
display: inline-block;
height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
color: #eee;
padding: 0px 22px 0px 22px;
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px -1px 1px;
}

#nav li a.nav_tier1:hover, #nav .current_page_item a.nav_tier1 {
    background: transparent url('../img/nav.bg.png') no-repeat center;
}

#nav li a.labs img {
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
}

/* Sub Navigation */

#nav .nav_2 {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.5);

background: #444;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#444), to(#222));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #222);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #222);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #222);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #222);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
behavior: url(/media/htc/PIE.htc);
}

#nav .nav_2 li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#nav .nav_2 li:last-child {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}   

#nav .nav_2 .nav_tier2 a {
display: block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
float: none;
}

#nav li:hover > .nav_2 {
    display: block;
}

*html #nav li:hover /* IE6 */ {
display: block;
}

#nav .nav_2 li a:hover {
    color: #CF982B;
}

/** Triangle Tip **/

#nav .nav_2 li:first-child a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: -15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #444;
z-index: 3000;
}

#nav .nav_2 li:first-child a:hover:after {
border-bottom-color: #444;
}

/** END Triangle Tip **/

/** END Sub Navigation **/

/* Clear floated elements */
#nav:after {
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}

*html #nav             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #nav { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

/** END Main Navigation **/
```

Applied on the following html navigation menu:

```
<ul id="nav" class="grid_6">
    <li>
        <a href="/labs/" class="nav_tier1">Labs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/contact/" class="nav_tier1">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/blogs/" class="nav_tier1">Blogs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/portfolio/" class="nav_tier1">Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="nav_2">
            <li>
                <a href="/presentations/" class="nav_tier2">Presentations</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Works on every browsers except for IE7/8/9**

This works perfectly on Safari, Chrome, Firefox but on IE7/IE8/IE9, the first time I hover over the portfolio link, the presentations child menu item does not show up properly on IE.

Only when I hover into the child menu item's anchor tag does the menu item now show up properly.

In addition, there seems to be a "ghost" menu item issue when I hover away from the child menu item.

Ghost menu showing up when I hover away from child menu item -

[image: ghost menu]

The first time the child menu item loads up, it loads up incorrectly like this -

[image: incorrect loading]

Comment: ie 6/7 doesn't play well with inline-block you might want to look into this: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Which is true but I have only one line that says

    #nav a {
        display: inline-block;

But that's not really related to the problem I am facing.  I can probably solve this display: inline-block; problem but that doesn't help me with my original bugs 
* ghost child menu showing (first picture)
* initial onhover doesn't load up the child menu correctly (2nd picture)

Comment: that one line might be your problem. Also, :hover doesn't work on other elements in ie6/7. it only works on anchor tags for those dinosaurs

Comment: Already tried that earlier on. That one line didn't change a thing in relation to those two bugs.

And I am more concerned about IE8 and IE9 rather than IE6 or 7.  7 - if possible. 6 - I won't even bother.

Comment: this might help: http://murphy.cz/ie7-hover-ghosts-bug/ although im not sure if it still happens in 8 or 9

Comment: already read that too but doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: you might want to remove some of the ie hacks and put them back in one by one to check what the problem is. you seem to have put all your hacks together in a single css file. or do you just include them separately in your markup?

Answer (score 0):

ie6/7 doesnt like inline block, you might want to add an external link and modify the css abit to get the result you wish.

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Victor, unfortunately inline-block wasn't the problem. I have disabled it completely but I am still getting exactly the same bugs on IE as described above.